# How to join the last five tables?

Tags: sql

```
declare @run_date DATETIME

select @run_date = '2016/02/19'

SELECT payment_id, Total = SUM(amount)
INTO #pym1
FROM PAYMENT_LINE
WHERE alloc_date IS NOT NULL
AND alloc_date < @run_date
AND (reversal_date <= @run_date or reversal_date IS NULL)
GROUP by payment_id


SELECT PAYMENT.payment_id, PAYMENT.payment_amount, Total
INTO #pym2
FROM PAYMENT,#pym1
WHERE PAYMENT.payment_id = #pym1.payment_id
AND Total > PAYMENT.payment_amount



SELECT payment_id, Difference_payment = (Total - payment_amount)    
INTO #pym3    
FROM #pym2    


SELECT DEBTOR.manufacturer_id, DEBTOR.debtor_id, alloc_date, PAYMENT.payment_id, PAYMENT.payment_amount, Total,Difference_payment
FROM PAYMENT,DEBTOR, #pym2,#pym3,PAYMENT_LINE    
WHERE PAYMENT.payment_id = DEBTOR.debtor_id  
AND PAYMENT_LINE.payment_id = PAYMENT.payment_id
AND DEBTOR.debtor_id = PAYMENT.payment_id
```

Comment: Clean up the formatting and maybe you will get some help.

Comment: Which are the last five tables? Please be willing to add some description and context in the question (by editing it).